# Реализация бизнес-логики в Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Пишу свой первый проект на Spring (онлайн банк). В банке есть три сущности: users, cards, и transactions.

Есть две роли: админа и пользователя. Админ будет выполнять CRUD операции с пользователями, картами и транзакциями. У пользователей будет возможность переводить деньги между собой по номеру карты и возможно заказ на открытие новой карты с подтверждением админа.

Слой DAO выполняет у меня доступ к базе. В нем реализованы операции CRUD.
В слое Servise у меня по идее должна быть остальная бизнес логика.

Но возникает следующий вопрос как лучше реализовать логику, просто расширив классы сервиса дополнительными методами?

[image: Структура]

Класс с сущностью

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
```

Класс c DAO

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeByUserId(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(id));
        if(user != null){
            session.delete(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(id));
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getListUsers() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        return users;
    }
```

Класс с Service

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.userDao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        this.userDao.updateUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeByUserId(int id) {
        this.userDao.removeByUserId(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        return this.userDao.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> getListUsers() {
        return this.userDao.getListUsers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вся бизнесс-логика обычно пишется в сервисах. И попробуйте использовать Spring Data Jpa вместо самописных DAO.